# sql and vb excel running

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have been battling for 2 days now and have finally thrown the towel in. I have changed zero in this script other than looking at a different set of fields. However the where clause is the same.

the error I am getting is ',', - which I cant find - but the debug is not specific

Code is

```
strSQL = "select rtrim(rtrim(dbo.BPSPayee(appointments.userid))) as Doctor,appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE,SUM(CASE WHEN appointments.internalid =21535 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Start, SUM(CASE WHEN appointments.internalid =21203 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Finish " & _
"from appointments" & _
 "where appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE >= convert(datetime,'" & Sheets("settings page").Range("c16") & _
"',105) AND appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE <= convert(datetime,'" & Sheets("settings page").Range("e16") & "',105) " & _
 "group by appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE,rtrim(rtrim(dbo.BPSPayee(appointments.userid))) "
```

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

If you want to debug your query, then print out the query *after* you have substituted variables in it.  Then you will see what you are running and what is failing.  It is mind-boggling that you would spend 20 minutes figuring this out -- much less 2 days.

I can see from your code that part of the query would look like:

```
from appointmentswhere appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE >= . . .
```

And that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have been on and off, so not a solid 2 days. Also I don't have "from appointmentswhere" in the script. It does have a space. I also have the same script using the same where clauses and that runs fine. So the issue is the ',',

Comment: I stand corrected. It was the appointmentswhere. Fixed.. I am use to working with SQL, but VBA SQL is a pain. When you say running a print out. What is this any idea

Comment: `Debug.Print strSQL` will print your SQL to the Immediate pane.